# Redraw plt figure after adding new axes in a loop

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

After spending hours and hours I still can't figure this, seemingly simple, question out. Here is small snippet of code I am trying to make work (I am running this as a jupyter notebook cell):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1, 11):
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 10, i)
  fig.canvas.draw()
  plt.draw()
  time.sleep(1)
```

I see my whole figure plotted after cell completes:
[image]

But I would like to see image redrawn every time when I add a new axes to it. Am I asking too much of matplotlib?

Comment: I think you're asking too much of IPython's inline backend. If you replace `time.sleep()` with `plt.pause()` and use an interactive backend, like matplotlib's `%matplolib notebook` you would get an interactively updating figure indeed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, would you mind sharing code snippet from above with updates you recommended? I am concerned that I might do something wrong trying incorporate your updated changes on my own...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, would you mind sharing code snippet from above with updates you recommended? I am concerned that I might do something wrong trying incorporate your updated changes on my own...

If I just do this:
```%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1, 11):
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 10, i)
  fig.canvas.draw()
  plt.draw()
  plt.pause(100)```
( sorry, can't figure out formatting in comments:( )
I am getting an error:
`Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`